# A build only device cannot be used to run this target for Any IOS Devis

Tags: flutter, xcode

I have a problem with xcode. When I start the application on an iPhone emulator the code works correctly.

However, when I want to start the application with "Any IOS device" or "Any Simulator IOS device" I have a problem:

**A build only device cannot be used to run this target.**

[image]

[image]

I don't understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: You must select a physical device or simulator in order to run iOS app

Comment: No, as I said, it works on an IOS emulator or on a physical iPhone but I need to archive the application to put it online on the Apple Store and to do this I have to select "Any IOS Device"

Comment: Solution :
YOU DO NOT NEED TO RUN THE APPLICATION DIRECTLY TO ARCHIVE IT!!

My problem is that I used "Start the active scheme" when I had to click on "Product > Archive", then the code executes and builds the project to put it directly in "App Store Connect"!

Comment: 1. Please don't put the answer in the question. I rolled back your last edit. Post an actual answer below. 2. Your question does not indicate in any way that your goal is to archive your project.

Comment: @HangarRash : I specified in the question that it works on an IOS emulator as well as on a mobile phone.  I also specify in the question that I want to use "Any IOS device" or "Any Simulator IOS device".  You must read the question before answering.  I found the solution and answered it in order to help future users who had the same problem as me.  I did not specify that I wanted it archived because I did not know the word and otherwise I would not have been blocked... Before responding stupidly and meanly, please think about the inconsistency of your words...!

Answer (score -1):

Select either a simluator or physical device to run your project. You must have selected Any IOS device,which is used usually to build or archive.

Comment: No, as I said, it works on an IOS emulator or on a physical iPhone but I need to archive the application to put it online on the Apple Store and to do this I have to select "Any IOS Device"

Comment: Solution :
YOU DO NOT NEED TO RUN THE APPLICATION DIRECTLY TO ARCHIVE IT!!

My problem is that I used "Start the active scheme" when I had to click on "Product > Archive", then the code executes and builds the project to put it directly in "App Store Connect"!

Answer (score -1):

Solution : YOU DO NOT NEED TO RUN THE APPLICATION DIRECTLY TO ARCHIVE IT!!

My problem is that I used "Start the active scheme" when I had to click on "Product > Archive", then the code executes and builds the project to put it directly in "App Store Connect"!